# Searching for values in different layers without nested for loops using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, geometry, features

I have a working process that uses a nested for loop to look through each feature of a point layer and search for a matching lat/lon of multiple line layers. It works fine but can take longer than I would like for large projects.

Is there a way to avoid looping through every point and line each time? Something like a lookup function?

This is what I currently have:

```py
for layer in layers: 
    name = layer.name()
    
    if "point" in name:
        lon_index = layer.fields().indexFromName("Lon")
        lat_index = layer.fields().indexFromName("Lat")
        
        for f in layer.getFeatures():
            Tlon = f[lon_index]
            Tlat = f[lat_index]
            
            for layer2 in layers:
                name = layer2.name()
                
                if "line" in name:
                    startLon_index = layer2.fields().indexFromName("startLon")
                    startLat_index = layer2.fields().indexFromName("startLat")
                    endLon_index = layer2.fields().indexFromName("endLon")
                    endLat_index = layer2.fields().indexFromName("endLat")
                        
                    for f2 in layer2.getFeatures():
                        startLon = str(f2[startLon_index])
                        startLat = str(f2[startLat_index])
                        endLon = str(f2[endLon_index])
                        endLat = str(f2[endLat_index])

                        if abs(float(startLon)-float(Tlon))<.001 and abs(float(Tlat)-float(startLat))<.001:
                            layer2.startEditing()
                            layer2.changeAttributeValue(f2.id(), start_index, f['Name'])
                            layer2.commitChanges()
                        if abs(float(endLon)-float(Tlon))<.001 and abs(float(Tlat)-float(endLat))<.001:
                            layer2.startEditing()
                            layer2.changeAttributeValue(f2.id(), end_index, f['Name'])
                            layer2.commitChanges()
                        else:
                            pass
```

I have seen some people use `get_feature`, but I get an error that says that is not defined:

```py
for layer in layers:
    name = layer.name()
    
    if "point" in name:
        pointlayer = layer

    for layer in layers: 
        name = layer.name()
        
        if "line" in name:
        
            for f2 in layer.getFeatures():
                f2.geometry(get_feature(pointlayer, 'startLon', 'Lon'))
```

Comment: `get_feature` is a QGIS expression engine function,  not PyQGIS. It can be used in the field calculator, geometry by expression tool, select by expression tool, data defined override expressions etc. It looks like you could benefit from checking out the `overlay_` series of functions in the field calculator.

Answer (score 5):

### Referring to a single feature

The [`getFeature()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#aa4886de4c49b0656cc0f47025fe2631b) method of the `QgsVectorLayer` class works as following:

> ```
> QgsFeature QgsVectorLayer::getFeature(QgsFeatureId fid) const
> ```
>
> Queries the layer for the feature with the given id.
>
> If there is no such feature, the returned feature will be invalid.

Features' ids are defined within a range `0 : layer.featureCount() - 1`

With the code below a feature with `id = 0` will be requested:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
feature = layer.getFeature(0)
```

Also one can try referring to a single feature by its id via the the [`getFeatures()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#ab0aee12fd9ff7c20b6587d6019f19edc) method together with the [`QgsFeatureRequest()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFeatureRequest.html) and [`setFilterFid()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFeatureRequest.html#af69925811b246513d7cb4aba7f959a03).

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
id = 0
feature = list(layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(id)))
```

Alternatively one can try using Python's [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) build-in method:

> Retrieve the next item from the iterator by calling its `__next__()`
> method. If default is given, it is returned if the iterator is
> exhausted, otherwise StopIteration is raised.

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
feature = next(layer.getFeatures())
```

However, the `next()` approach is not wealthy, because it will provide access only to *the next item from the iterator*, only good if your feature is the first in a list.

### Referring to several features

If only targeting features' ids should be requested, then one case get them via the [`getFeatures()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#ab0aee12fd9ff7c20b6587d6019f19edc) method together with the [`QgsFeatureRequest()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFeatureRequest.html) and [`setFilterFids()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFeatureRequest.html#a59955b7d1e3d23b32020465ce41e2da1).

With the code below three features with `id = 0`, `id = 2`, and `id = 5` will be requested:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
ids = [0,2,5]
features = list(layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids(ids)))
```

### Referring to all features

In case when all features should be requested use simply the `getFeatures()` method:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
features = list(layer.getFeatures())
```